# Condition in the queryset does not work

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to add a condition into a queryset of a form, this is my source code :

```
class ContainerForm(forms.ModelForm):
vehicle = forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False,queryset=Vehicle.objects.filter(id = vehicle.id),widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
```

but while debugging it says vehicle.id is not defined! Any help would be appreciated!

my objective is to have dynamic field into my form

Comment: Yes, it is not defined. Where is it supposed to come from?

Comment: it supposed to come from url

Answer (score 0):

This is class definition. The variable `vehicle` is not defined when you construct `ModelChoiceField`. As simple as that.

What you're trying to do is to limit options of a model form's field depending on the instance.

See the documentation which handles your case:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#fields-which-handle-relationships